# Expose local Docker WP site to network and internet

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, tunnel

I'm having an issue that I can't seem to articulate enough to find an answer to.

**The problem:**

I want to expose my local 10-up local WP docker site to my network (so people can help me log in and write for it when they're on my LAN), and also have a tunnel so that I can send a link to someone over the internet so they can view the site for approvals etc. I'd rather not go through a staging env if I don't have to.

**My thoughts**

When I had initially gotten into Docker, I can't remember what video I was watching, but I ran a specific command (something like docker -p 80:8080) that exposed the ports so that all of the computers on my network were able to view the site. Now that I'm using a Docker image (10-up WP-Local Docker image [https://github.com/10up/wp-local-docker](http://HERE)), it uses a docker-compose.yml file, so it handles spinning up the various needed containers.

I can't for the life of me figure out how to get it back to the way I had it before. I'm sure there's something I can put in the docker-compose file that will automatically do this, and I'm *sure* there's some program or package that I can install that will create a tunnel that I can use to show my site over the internet. I basically just need a push in the right direction. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The equivalant of the -p inside the docker compose file is the ports section, this should expose the specified port for the container to receive traffic on that port. 
Thus if your machine is exposed over the network or the public internet, exposing the port using docker should allow your application to receive traffic on the specified port.
For the phpfm service you should expose the port 9000 to make the service reachable

```
phpfpm:
    image: 10up/phpfpm
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - memcached
      - elasticsearch
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
      - "./wordpress:/var/www/html"
      - "./config/php-fpm/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini"
      - "./config/php-fpm/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini"
    restart: always
    extra_hosts:
      - "docker-local.dev:172.18.0.1"
```

Comment: So I only need expose the ports in the phpfpm ports list? I'm assuming because all of the internal server routing is still staying put, and the outputs are only being piped through this? Sorry - I'm just trying to wrap my head around this.

I also noticed the extra_hosts -- Is that where I put what I want the name to be (aside from localhost)? I figured I'd ask since it's in your answer. Thanks!

Comment: for the extra_hosts this will add a DNS entry inside the container where for example `docker-local.dev` will be resolved to `172.18.0.1` from inside the container.

Comment: Does that equate to being able to link and put 'docker-local.dev' in the address bar? Sorry - I'm new to these features, and still wrapping my head around them.

**EDIT**
Is there a page that you can link me to that explains this stuff? My problem is not knowing how these components interact to be able to ask a question that will actually help me solve my problem. I think a point in the right direction might really help me out.

Comment: It didn't work. I added:

ports:
  -  "9000:9000"

to my docker-compose, and it didn't do anything. I can't connect to localhost:9000

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Like the previous speaker already explained the `-p` is equivalent to:

```
ports:
  - "8183:80"
```

Where your local listner is the first value `8183` and the internal docker value is `80` as you already known from `-p`

```
php:
    build: php7-fpm
    ports:
        - 9000
    volumes:
        - ../src:/var/www/
nginx:
    build: nginx
    ports:
        - 8183:80
    links:
        - php
    volumes_from:
        - php
    volumes:
        - ./logs/nginx/:/var/log/nginx
    tty: true
```

In this configuration the docker container `nginx` will be mapped on the host machine to `0.0.0.0:8183` or `127.0.0.0:8183` or `your_external_ip:8183` if the firewall on your computer exposes the port to the external network.

I hope that helps a little bit.

Regards

Edit:

The property `extra_host` is the same that you will use in cli context `--add-host`. Maybe have a look into [extra_host](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extra_hosts)

Comment: So I'm adding ports to the docker-compose, right? Seems like the one you're showing isn't like the one I have.

Comment: something like this:
`nginx:`
`ports:`
`- "8080:80" #"your machine port":"docker port"`

Comment: I added just that, and it doesn't seem to be working. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you tried in browser to open 127.0.0.1:8080?

Otherwise please post your docker-compose.yml

Comment: I think I found the issue:

I was adding the ports under phpfrm, but it *is* redirecting when I nest it under nginx. Is that where it's supposed to go? Now how would I go about tunneling it?